# how read documents (pdf, docx, etc) using orca in lubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, orca, text-to-speech

Hello I had installed Orca in lubuntu 12.10. But when i open it i just get the container box with tabs for preferences, help, about, exit. How do i make it read documents? I want to read a pdf document. Is it possible? Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have put my question core clearly. I want a computer voice to read out loud my pdf, docx documents. How can I dothis. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to be able to open/edit your documents then, for pdf you can use `sudo apt-get install evince-gtk` to install/update default pdf reader. for docx you can use `libre office` or `open office`

Answer (score 0):

You can Download the other TTS software like [Free TTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php).